# Radio button to get a simple tab effect in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

### How to create a setting such that there are two radiobuttons on the layout

I have made a better representation from my last question

**Radio buttons**

- RadioButton1
- RadioButton2

[image]

---

Click on `RadioButton1` .. `Activity1` should display on the `same screen`

Click on `RadioButton1` again `Activity2` should display on the `same screen`

similarly to RadioButton2

---

This i have performed using tabs with tabhost

Since the design of tabhost is rigid ..... is it possible to make as above

---

**If so, How can it be done ....?**

### {edit}

I didnt know how to use radiobutton but i have tried something similar

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

**Fragment_1.java**

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment{

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_1, container, false);

            final EditText edtxtPersonName_Fragment = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtxtPersonName);
            Button btnSayHi_Fragment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSayHi);

            btnSayHi_Fragment.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String name = edtxtPersonName_Fragment.getText().toString();

                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                    Fragment_2 f2 = (Fragment_2) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content_2);

                    if(f2 != null && f2.isInLayout())
                    {
                        f2.setName(name);
                    }

                    Activity activity = getActivity();

                    if(activity != null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Say&ing Hi in Progress...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            return view;


        }

    }
```

**Fragment_2.java**

```
public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment {

    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_2, container, false);        
        return view;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtViewResult);
        txtName.setText("Hi " + name);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content_1"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.Fragment_1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content_2"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentexample.Fragment_2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/fragment_basic -->
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Still i got log errors

**LOG::**

```
10-13 15:56:44.837: D/AndroidRuntime(326): Shutting down VM
10-13 15:56:44.837: W/dalvikvm(326): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment/com.example.fragment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.example.fragment.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  ... 11 more
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.fragment-1.apk]
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
10-13 15:56:45.117: E/AndroidRuntime(326):  ... 20 more
10-13 15:56:49.207: I/Process(326): Sending signal. PID: 326 SIG: 9
```

Comment: package name is `com.example.fragment` instead `com.example.fragmentexample`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `RadioButtons`, you should use `TabHost` for this.

See the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236958/819355

Another good option is to use `ViewPager`, see official docs here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: i did understand how to do with the example you have pointed with tab Host ...... but .... my requirement :: Say there are two tabs .... click on tab1 .... activity 1 must show in screen below .... click tab1 again activity2 show display in screen below ..... how to tweak your answer to that ... any ideas ?

Comment: in the linked answer see "Tab1Fragment" which you can duplicate to be "Tab2Fragment" and even more if needed. Each fragment will appear on screen when you click the tab on the top.

Comment: indeed true ..... i achieved that .... What i am refering is let me clear my explanation:: tab1 click -> activity1 should display in the screen below ........ tab1 click again(must ) -> activity2 must display in the screen below .... i should not use second tab to view secoond activity ...... its like a flip flop cyclic order of a button that switches between activities ... hope i am clear

Comment: yep, got it, you can set the OnTabChangeListener to listen to tab clicks, and use setCurrentTab to change the fragments manually.

Comment: Can you look at this question ..... http://stackoverflow.com/q/19354458/2825729 ..... How to make the changes as u suggested .... i have posted new dquestion... thanks