# Switching tabs within tabs

Tags: android

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            Tab2Fragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
            Tab3Fragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

**Tab1Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment  {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_view, container, false);

        return V;
    }
}
```

**Tab2Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment  {

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2_view, container, false);

            return V;
        }
    }
```

**Tab3Fragment.java**

```
public class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment  {

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3_view, container, false);

            return V;
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"

        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

---

**My Output is** ::

[image]

### How can i make the above code FLIP FLOP in nature

- Click `tab 1` ---- > `Activity 1` should display.
- Click on selected `tab 1` (again) ------> `Activity 2` should display.
- Click on selected `tab 1` (again) for **third time** ----> `Activity
  1` should display `again`.

**Kind of Flip FLOP NATURE**

### How can i detect on click events on the selected tab and meet by above specifications

Any iDeas

Answer (score 1):

you have to maintain your tab clicks and when you click on tab you have to manager a counter which is increment by click and when you click on tabs you will check that condition according to click counter...

Comment: So Harshit has the right idea. You have to store the current state of the tab in the button by using tags. So when tab1 is being hidden button1 should have the tag "hidden" and when it is visible it should have the tag "visible". When the button is pressed u decide what u want to do by using that tag. So when button1 is clicked is the tag is visible you should hide the tab and switch the buttons tag and etc for the opposite. Similarly for the remaining button tabs

Answer (score 1):

Ohk i will explain this step by step
1.Just take on class like singlton class or you should take one static int counter in any class.
2.when ever you click on tab then on tab clicklistner just first you check what is the value of counter  if counter==1 then first activity call 
if  counter==2 then 2nd activity call
counter==3 then third activity call

and at the end just increase your counter and if counter>3 then counter=1 ;

counter is static so in whole execution of app it will be constant and same :)

Comment: no its very simple dear just do it one time take one static counter only and increase and check it simple

Comment: How to launch ... using intents .... i am confused :( .... i have no problems with regular activities.... in tab .... i am stuck

Comment: dear in fragment there is no intent, perhaps we use add view and sub view i think u take one tutorial tour on this fragment this time i m little busy but latter i m available on b19bhanu@gmail.com on fb gmail twitter :)

Comment: yess ofcourse heyyy u can do one thing also just check your condition here when u write this line  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);  just chk counter value if it is 1 then  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);   if counter value is 2 then  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab2Fragment.class, null); and so on you can add me on fb also

Comment: @ Bhanu Sharma ... please can u edit your answer ... i tried ... not working  ... At least the main activity:(

Comment: just do one think dear make all three view in one xml in different  different layout and visibility gone ok and add this xml in Tab1Fragment.class after  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);   you r in Tab1Fragment.class then you check counter and according to counter rest of two layout's  view gone.