# Android: Creating tabs within a fragment

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs, fragment, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

This question is a bit hard to word, I will try my best.

I have this android app that uses a navigation drawer, so within the main_activity, the navigation drawer would change the different kinds of fragments that I want.

Within one fragment, I want it to be able to have four tabs.  The functionality of the tabs is very simple as it basically just display some pictures and data.  However, I don't think android allows you to have a tabhost within a fragment.

I can achieve a similar result by creating my own buttons at the top and it dynamically changes the View that is within this fragment, however, I am wondering is there a more intuitive way of achievement the same result?

Comment: Why do you think Android does not allow Tabs inside a Fragment? That works just fine.

Comment: Can you give me a brief overview of how that would work? because from the tutorials, tabs would have to be hosted within a tab activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TabHost` inside a `Fragment` just fine. A `TabActivity` is not necessary to host the tabs. `TabActivity` only provides some functionality that you can also add to a `Fragment` yourself. Check out the [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) docs, especially the section about [addTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#addTab%28android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec%29). You can also search here on SO and you will find very helpful posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227855/tabhost-with-fragments-and-fragmentactivity).