# How to Implement Tabs within Fragment Class?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement slide menu using navigation drawer class. In that am using Fragment class, within that how to implement activity with the Extend of Fragment?

Comment: what is your progress so far and where are you having problems? and "*how to implement activity with the Extend of Fragment?*" is conceptually **wrong**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use this example.[here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)

in androidhive example. and can seee this also.[here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/)

and can see this solution of stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227855/tabhost-with-fragments-and-fragmentactivity)

i think it may help you.

Comment: I need to implement with help of Activity only not an Fragment Activity.

Comment: have you tried it by yourself ..,post your code