# How to use tabhost to display tabs in fragments

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have used activity to display 3 tabs using tab host but i now want to use FRAGMENT to display the tabs, instead of the activity so i want the equivalent code for using tab host in fragment.

Comment: go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227855/tabhost-with-fragments-and-fragmentactivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227855/tabhost-with-fragments-and-fragmentactivity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this tutorial 
http://android.codeandmagic.org/android-tabs-with-fragments/

Hope it helps