# Not displaying navigation drawer with TabHostFragment

Tags: android, tabs

Few days ago I implemented TabHostFragment inside my `NavigationDrawerMenu`, the problem is when I try to open the `NavigationDrawer` it does not.
My app does not crash but it does not open the `NavigationDrawer` and I don't know what I'm missing. I guess the problem is with the `setContentView()`, because I use another Layout to use my `TabHostFragment`, I tried to implement this `TabHostFragment` in my activity_main, but I don't know how to put it correctly.

Here's my MainActivity.class

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    // saber si esta abierto
    public boolean mDrawerOpened;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    //para ponerlo visible
    public MenuItem mi;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        //AyudaSugerencias
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff1d97dd));
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(
                        Html.fromHtml("<font color='ffffff'>"
                                + mTitle + "</font>"));

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mDrawerOpened = false;
                syncState();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(
                        Html.fromHtml("<font color='ffffff'>"
                                + mDrawerTitle + "</font>"));

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mDrawerOpened = true;
                syncState();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.ofertasRefresh:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                return true;
            case R.id.newOffer:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new TipusNouProducte()).commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        if (mDrawerOpened) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_search);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.newOffer);
        }
        if (!mDrawerOpened) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.ofertasRefresh, Menu.NONE, mTitle);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        //Fragment fragment = null;  ---Removed for test, because if I don't remove this line couldn't execute the app because fragment can not call a FragmentActivity....

        if(position == 0){

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);

            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
                    MisOfertasFragment.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
                    RecomendacionesFragment.class, null);
        }
        else
        {
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            Fragment fragment = null;

            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    fragment = new RecomendacionesFragment();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new LocalizacionFragment();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new ListaProductosFragment();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    fragment = new ConfiguracionFragment();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    fragment = new AyudaSugerenciasFragment();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fragment = new AyudaSugerencias();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }


            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); /// here says that replace android.app.Fragment in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied...

                // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                // error in creating fragment
                Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
            }
        }
    }






    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);

    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Now I'm gonna explain the code...

I think the thing that I'm doing wrong is the `setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);`, because I replace the old layout (where I've got the NavigationDrawer by this other, and I don't call it back anymore), maybe it isn't the problem, but is the only solution i guess...

Also if on `displayView()` I put number 3, it opens correctly but then when I try to go to the first, it crashes.

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
```

**EDIT**

activity_main.xml (where I've got my navigationDrawer)

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

tabhost.xml (Where I've got my Tabs)

```
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**EDIT LOGCAT ERROR**

```
03-04 16:53:05.708    2232-2232/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 2232
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:330)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:13406)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2707)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2714)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3919)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3733)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3678)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3654)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: where have you reached with this so far ?

Comment: Can't find the way to get the navigation Drawer when I'm on Tabhost layout, it's obvious because it doesn't contain any navigation drawer, but as I said... My question is how to "link" those two Layouts in one (Is what I thought), if exists other way to do it I don't find it...

Comment: As I understand, you have added code for Navigation Drawer, but it is not working in this `Activity`, right ?

Comment: Yep, I don't know how to connect the Tabhost Layout with Activitymain Layout, because they are two different things

Comment: can you post XML of `Activity` layout ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72248/discussion-between-zygoteinit-and-skizo).

Comment: are you online now ?

Comment: @ZygoteInit Yes I am :)

Comment: I'm online, are you there to do the stuff? :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit Let's do it then :) I'm on chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `Fragment` class called `MyTabHostFragment` like this:

```
public class MyTabHostFragment extends Fragment{

    public MyTabHostFragment(){

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabhost, container, false);            
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
                MisOfertasFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
                RecomendacionesFragment.class, null);
    }

}
```

Now in your `MainActivity`, modify your `displayView()` method like this:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new MyTabHostFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new RecomendacionesFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new LocalizacionFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ListaProductosFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new ConfiguracionFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new AyudaSugerenciasFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new AyudaSugerencias();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); /// here says that replace android.app.Fragment in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied...

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

And make sure that in the `onCreate()` method of your `MainActivity` you have

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and not

```
setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
```

Try this. This should work.

**EDIT:**

The crash in the error posted is due to a bug in the Android framework itself. This bug has been documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686282/android-fragmenttabhost-not-fully-baked-yet), [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40035) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53230). I am still looking for a proper workaround to this.

Comment: See this dear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901977/fragmenttabhost-no-tab-known-for-tag-null :)

Comment: I've added a bounty to see if anyone can help us to solve this error! :D

Comment: I have some advice for you ... if you re-edit the question, just make some small changes, then it will go to the top of the questions list :)

Comment: Oh, I see... I will now!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advantage".

Comment: @JohnSaunders My bad, sorry :l