# Fragment duplicates when I go to another Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Actually, this is my main problem. I've got a `NavigationDrawer` and I was changing lot of things about it; because I've added a `TabHostFragment` inside of it. *The problem is when I'm in one `Fragment`, I've an `ActionBar` icon that goes to another `Fragment`. At the time to do this, it works perfect; but when I go to another `Fragment`, it still on the back of the new `Fragment`.* I tried to put a `BackGround` color of each `Fragment` and it isn't visible.

The problem is that the transaction is OK; but when I'm in the other `Fragment`, when I press in a `BlankSpace` (For example) and on the old `Fragment` has a button here with a `Toast`, it's still showing this `Toast` on the new `Fragment`.

Here are a little examples of what happens maybe with images, you can understand better my question:

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

This main problem comes when I go trough this `Fragment` (I call it on `MainActivity`) that has no sense; because I want to call it when I'm on a specific `Fragment`; but it's in the only part that I can call this `Fragment`...

This is the `MainActivity`, where I call this `FragmentTransaction`:

```
case R.id.newOffer:
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TipusNouProducte());
    ft.commit();
    return true;
```

And by the way, I leave here the code from my `NavigationDrawer` for you that always when I'm going through a `Fragment`, it says ***"Error on creating Fragment"***:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TabHostFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new LocalizacionFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new ListaProductosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ConfiguracionFragment(this);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new AyudaSugerenciasFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new AyudaSugerencias();
            break;
        case 6:
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit(); 

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

If you need more code that you think can cause this problem, feel free to ask me; then I'll update ASAP.

**TabHostFragment.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

MainActivity code looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    // saber si esta abierto
    public boolean mDrawerOpened;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    //para ponerlo visible
    public MenuItem mi;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        //navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        //AyudaSugerencias
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff1d97dd));
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(
                    Html.fromHtml("<font color='ffffff'>"
                        + mTitle + "</font>"));

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mDrawerOpened = false;
                syncState();

            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(
                    Html.fromHtml("<font color='ffffff'>"
                        + mDrawerTitle + "</font>"));

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                mDrawerOpened = true;
                syncState();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            case R.id.ofertasRefresh:
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_search:
                return true;
            case R.id.newOffer:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TipusNouProducte());
                ft.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        if (mDrawerOpened) {
            menu.removeItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.menu_search);
            menu.removeItem(R.id.newOffer);
        }
        if (!mDrawerOpened) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.ofertasRefresh, Menu.NONE, mTitle);
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new TabHostFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new LocalizacionFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new ListaProductosFragment();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new ConfiguracionFragment(this);
                break;
            case 4:
                fragment = new AyudaSugerenciasFragment();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragment = new AyudaSugerencias();
                break;
            case 6:
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

`TabHostFragment` looks like:

```
public class TabHostFragment extends Fragment {
    // Declaring our tabs and the corresponding fragments.
    public TabHostFragment(){

    }
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_host_test2, container, false);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Mis ofertas").setIndicator("Mis ofertas"),
            MisOfertasFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Mis recomendaciones").setIndicator("Mis recomendaciones"),
            RecomendacionesFragment.class, null);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: show ur `fragmentActivity` xml..

Comment: wich one? TipusNouProducte?

Comment: wait, i think u have two issues. first, u have error and second, the second fragment is coming behind tabs rite?..for error pls post log..

Comment: The thing is I've not any error on LogCat it only shows this Log `Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");` sometimes... but there is no problem on my logcat

Comment: ok, show ur xml where u added TabPageIndicator and ViewPager..

Comment: @MSGadag I've added TabHost.XML

Comment: set ur `realtabcontent` height as 0dp and try...

Comment: I request you to post the code of `MainActivity` and `TabHostFragment` if possible. If I understand correctly, the two `Fragment`s in the `FragmentTabHost` are overlapping, right ?

Comment: I posted the TabHost image but it does with all of my Fragments it's not the only Fragment that are overlaped, I think the problem is when I do the FragmentTransaction this Fragment is never closed and then it never dissapear... But anyways I'm gonna try the realtabcontent to 0dp and I'll post my MainActivity and TabHostFragment....

Comment: @MSGadag It didn't do anything new... nice try :(

Comment: @Y.S. Updated my question did you see that?

Comment: @Skizo: yes I did, please have a look at my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain that this is the cause of your problem, but one thing that's definitely wrong is the use of the ***native*** `FragmentManager` instead of the one from the support library.

In your code, replace

```
case R.id.newOffer:
    android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TipusNouProducte());
    ft.commit();
    return true;
```

with

```
case R.id.newOffer:
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new TipusNouProducte());
    ft.commit();
    return true;
```

You have used the ***support library's*** `FragmentManager` at other places in your code, so you should continue to use that everywhere.

Also, `TipusNouProducte` should extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and **NOT**
`android.app.Fragment`.

I will update this answer if I find more issues.

Comment: nvm I did it by my own :) wish the best for you thanks for help.