# Where should I put the codes?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I created some tabs with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227855/tabhost-with-fragments-and-fragmentactivity) tutorial (first answer)
But I don't know where should I put my other codes in Tab1Fragment.java!
I'm programming for Android And these are the codes:

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.applicationname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1"),
            Tab1Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2"),
            Tab2Fragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3"),
            Tab3Fragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

Tab1Fragment.java

```
package com.example.applicationname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment  {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_view, container, false);

        return V;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are programming in Java? Then add the tag. Are you programming for Android? Then add that tag too. And please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try to clarify your query and post your code that you have tried so far

Comment: use it in onCreateView() in Tab1Fragment Class.

Comment: M.Qaqas Pervez, I tried it before, and it doesn't work. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to implement tabs is through *TabLayout* and *ViewPager*.

*MainActivity*

This code will come under onStart/onCreate method.

```
TabLayout tabLay = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    tabLay.addTab(tabLay.newTab().setText("Collections"));
    tabLay.addTab(tabLay.newTab().setText("Loyalty"));
    tabLay.addTab(tabLay.newTab().setText("Orders"));


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.userTabs);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLay.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLay.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLay.getTabAt(0).setText("Collections");
    tabLay.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.collage);
    tabLay.getTabAt(1).setText("Loyalty");
    tabLay.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.heart_outline);
    tabLay.getTabAt(2).setText("Orders");
    tabLay.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.cart_outline);




    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLay));



    tabLay.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


}
```

*Pager Adapter*

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
 public int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = 3;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            CollectionsFragment tab1 = new CollectionsFragment();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            LoyaltyFragment tab2 = new LoyaltyFragment();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            OrdersFragment tab3 = new OrdersFragment();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}}
```

*Fragment*

```
public class CollectionsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_collections, container, false);


    }
}
```

This implementation will be similar for every fragment.

This should do it.

[image: End Result]

Comment: thanks but I'm a newbie and don't even know where should I put the codes for each tab!

Comment: Put them in seperate java files in your app/src/java directory with the MainActivity.java file.