# How to set a ViewPager inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

I need to place a ViewPager inside of a fragment, but I have two fragments, Fragment 1 is my MENU, and Fragment 2 I want to use as a ViewPagerIndicator.

But a fragment can't have another fragment...  what do I need to do for that?

[image]

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Starting in Android 4.2, there are nested fragments.http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments The support library now also includes support for this for older Android versions.

So you can do something like this:

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    }
```

Full implementation available here: https://github.com/marcoRS/nested-fragments/tree/master/src/com/burnside/digital/nestedfragments

Comment: But is not possible because i cant put a FragmentActivity inside of my Fragment 2 , because the fragment parent is a FragmentActivity, and the child(fragment 2) needs to be a fragmentActivity to have the tabs.. and in the github example dont put a fragment inside an other fragment.

Comment: Why do you even need to have fragment 1? Can't you just have a viewpager that references different fragments and then have Fragment 2 below it?

Comment: but the fragment 1 is always the same and this would look like changes, and do not want that.. some idea?

Comment: yeah Simply use getChildFragmetManager() Instead of getFragmentManager() or getSupportFragmentManger(),when you initiating adapter.
And it will definitely works :) ,Happy Coding.

Comment: It Worked. I was using getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager() when initializing the ViewPagerAdapter inside fragment .

Comment: Full Implementation Link Dead.....................................

Comment: The example is no longer functional!

Answer (score 38):

You must use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`  to get the `FragmentManger` inside a Fragment.
But you should not use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` rather than `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

Comment: "Not use FragmentStatePagerAdapter rather than FragmentPagerAdapter".. Unraveling the triple negative, you mean we SHOULD USE FragmentPagerAdapter, right? And why is that?

Comment: "But you should not use FragmentStatePagerAdapter rather than FragmentPagerAdapter."  

Once again `FragmentPagerAdapter` saved my day. This happening to me second time but i didnt realize until saw this.  Reason:  
if you try to use FragmentStatePagerAdapter in a viewPager that in a fragment your option menu could be messed up(or doesn't show up at all) if you navigate to another page and came back

Answer (score 18):

Just use [getChildFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()) instead of [getSupportFragmentManager()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()) inside Fragments.

#### Inside Fragments

```
new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

#### Inside Activity

```
new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

### Simple Code

### `fragment_sample.xml` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### `SampleFragment.java` class

```
public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
        return fragmentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // find views by id
        ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

        // attach tablayout with viewpager
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        // add your fragments
        adapter.addFrag(new SampleFragment(), "Tab1");
        adapter.addFrag(new SampleFragment2(), "Tab2");
        adapter.addFrag(new SampleFragment3(), "Tab3");

        // set adapter on viewpager
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

### `ViewPagerAdapter.java` class

```
// common adapter for all view pager in your project.
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add("");
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

**Important Related Links**

- [Difference between getSupportFragmentManager() and getChildFragmentManager()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14740445/6891563)
- [getSupportFragmentManager() versus getFragmentManager() in android 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12380367/6891563)
- [Difference between FragmentPagerAdapter and FragmentStatePagerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18747975/6891563)

Comment: `SampleFragment()` in the line `adapter.addFrag(new SampleFragment(), "Tab1");` should be changed to `SampleFragment1()`, since `SampleFragment()` is already defined as the fragment holding the `ViewPager` @Khemraj

Answer (score 4):

it is possible. try to do this code view_pager_fragment.xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

ViewPagerFragment

```
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tracks, container, false);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());``

  

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return new FirstFragment();
        if(position == 1) return new SecoundFragment();
        if(position == 2) return new LoginFragment();
        throw new IllegalStateException("Position is unexpectedly " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position == 0) return "First";
        if(position == 1) return "Secound";
        if(position == 2) return "Login";
        throw new IllegalStateException("Position is unexpectedly " + position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Android Support V4 library, you can add a fragment inside another fragment. Try to use it, it may can resolve your problem.

Comment: But is not possible because i cant put a FragmentActivity inside of my Fragment 2 , because the fragment parent is a FragmentActivity, and the child(fragment 2) needs to be a fragmentActivity to have the tabs.. some idea?

Comment: Oh but wait, you can just put 2 fragment into a fragment without fragmentActivity, you know ? Or maybe you have your reasons to do it...

Answer (score 0):

After Read some examples, you cant have a FragmentActivity inside a fragmentActivity.
Is not necesary to have two fragments and this need be a FragmentPageAdapter...  i only need to do this.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:measureWithLargestChild="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="First" >
        </Button>

<Button
            android:id="@+id/last"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last" >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Source:
http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-fragmentpageradapter-example/

Answer (score 0):

I'm use ViewPager2 in a Fragment and find it works fine:

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

public MyViewPagerAdapter (@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        default:
            return new Fragment1();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

}

And create:

```
MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter ((FragmentActivity) context);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setUserInputEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).