# How to display a Listview inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hi Guys i want to display a ListView (Code Below)
inside a Fragment!
How to do that.
I have already Searched but i dont found anything that solved that.

Thank you Guys for help :-D

ExperimentsList.java:

```
public class ExperimentsList extends AppCompatActivity {

public ListView lv1;
public String[] listentext = {"Cola&Mentos","2","3","4"};



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_experiments_list);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listenadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(ExperimentsList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listentext);
    lv1.setAdapter(listenadapter);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {

            switch (lv1.getPositionForView(view)) {

                case 0:{
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(ExperimentsList.this, ColaMentos.class);

                    final int result = 1;

                    ExperimentsList.this.startActivity(myIntent);

                }





            }



        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to display a list in the viewpager under the tabs.
For this you can get the viewpager and set a FragmentPagerAdaptor to it, which returns an instance of a ListFragment from the getItem method.

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

In pager adaptor:

```
  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                    return MyListFragment.newInstance("");
                }

            .....
            .....
    }
```

You can write your implementation of ListFragment to show your list data.

Comment: Thanks for help but i want to Display this Code as a Fragment do you know what i mean i want to have a Fragment with this Viewpager

Comment: OK. Just saw your edit. If the fragment needs to contain only a listview, then just use a ListFragment. If you need other elements as well in the fragment, then create a layout xml which has a listview and use this to inflate the fragment.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [How set ViewPager inside a Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073541/how-set-viewpager-inside-a-fragment)

Comment: sorry i meant listview

Comment: its the Code of a Listview i want to display this Listview inside a Fragment

Comment: Then you can use a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `activity_experiments_list` to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/one_frag"
        android:name="biz.progmar.testapp.ListViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add ListViewFragment.class:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] listentext = {"Cola&Mentos","2","3","4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> listenadapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listentext);
        //load the simple_layout.xml which contains only one ListView.
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_layout,container,false);
        //use id="lv1" to capture the ListView
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv1);
        //set the adapter
        listView.setAdapter(listenadapter);
        return view;
    }

}
```

let the inflater to inflate `simple_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then, you can see in your activity layout,It also has a ListView