# Google maps v2 android with Action bar activity add and switch to another fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have an app that is extending ActionBarActivity and is using google maps as fragment. I obtain the map like this:

```
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mMap = fm.getMap();
```

So my question is, how to add another fragment and how to switch between them ? I've been googling and searching for solution but found nothing yet.

Comment: did you declare your fragment in xml?

Comment: I havent done anything so far. I am not home at this domain so I am searching for some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FragmentTransaction.replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.support.v4.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) to replace fragments. Example:

```
Fragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

For more check [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658675/replacing-a-fragment-with-another-fragment-inside-activity-group).

If you are using a support package (v4, v7 or v11) or you are targeting API< 14 use [getSupportgetSupportFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager()). Else, for API>=14 use [getFragmentManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getFragmentManager()).

Comment: I suggest to add transaction.addToBackStack(null); before transaction.commit(); this will ensure that when you press back button the current one will disappear and the one before it will show.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it. Just one question. cna i use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() ?

Comment: if you use API>14, you [should use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380367/getsupportfragmentmanager-versus-getfragmentmanager-in-android-3-0) `getFragmentManager`.

Comment: But I am targetting API 21 so I need to use getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: I updated my answer according to your issue, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306197/using-getfragmentmanager-vs-getsupportfragmentmanager) for more too.